# Upload button for multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash, plupload

I want my file upload to be very simple, and what could be simpler than just a single button. The requirements are that you should be able to upload multiple files at once. It would definitely be an advantage if I could add file format filters as well, and design the button by myself (including the hover event).

I searched and found [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), which seemed to be awesome with the easy setup and functionality, but I can't quite figure out how to create my button; I've only found their [Custom upload](http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php), which prints out the file names and requires at least one click on another button before it's done (and I can apparently not add any hover-attribute). I tried to edit the JavaScript to make the form be sent after all the files had been added, but failed.

Are there any better alternatives, or could someone help me on the right path?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plupload is mmost likely your best bet for an easy to implement, easy to customize full file uploader. However if you want to take a basic one and style it, check out something like: http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2009/06/14/swfupload-jquery-plugin/

This one is probably better:

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/